# Database for distant stars

Tags: data-analysis

I'm looking for a database of stars that lists as many of the known stars as possible. Ideally, I'd like it to have information on the radius of the stars, the distance from the earth and the classification.
What source(s) exist for this data (preferably in a simple form)

Comment: For "a dataset"? Any dataset? Your title mentions a "database" and "distant stars". Can you clarify exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: Most catalogs contain distance and classification, I can't think of any that contain size as that's unknown for most stars.

Comment: The number of stars with measured sizes is very small. One can attempt to estimate radii based on other measurements, but that would normally be left for the end user.

Comment: It would be helpful to know how you plan to use this database.  Is it for some statistical project? or a computer game? or something else.  One issue you may find is being overwhelmed. There are several billion stars in the Gaia data releases. And so accessing the data "in simple form" is tricky.

Answer (score 2):

One possible such dataset is the [HYG database](https://github.com/astronexus/HYG-Database).

120,000 stars, has the properties you listed, and consists of a single CSV file.

One possible issue is what you mean by "size". HYG has the absolute magnitude of stars, but not mass nor radius.